# How can I resolve the error "undefined reference to `yyerror'"?

Tags: parsing, visual-studio-code, gcc, bison, flex-lexer

I've been following the youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fFRxWtRibC8

I've created the lexer.l file with the following:

```
%{
    /* definitions */
    #include "parser.tab.h"
%}
    /* rules */
%%

[0-9]+ {yylval.num = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER; }
\n {return EOL;}
. {}
 
%%

yywrap() {}

int main() {
    yylex();

    return 0;
}
```

and the parser.y file with the following:

```
%{
    /* definitions */
%}

%union{
    int num;
    char sym;
}

%token EOL
%token<num> NUMBER
%type<num> exp
%token PLUS

/* rules */
%%

input: 
    exp EOL  {printf("%d\n", $1); }
|   EOL;
exp: 
    NUMBER { $$ = $1; }
|   exp PLUS exp { $$ = $1 + $3; }
;

%%

int main() {
    yyparse();

    return 0;
}

void yyerror (char* s) {
    printf ("ERROR: %s\n", s);

    return 0; 
}
```

When running the command "gcc lex.yy.c parser.tab.c", I'm getting the following error:
undefined reference to `yyerror'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: look in your c files if the function `yyerror()` is there somewhere, delete all your generated c code and create them again, use a build tool to never forget to generate new code when needed

Comment: I don't see how that can work at all, since you have a `main()` definition in both of the source files. So I presume you're not following the video you refer to precisely (it notes that you need to delete `main()` from the lexer file). That doesn't explain why the linker can't find `yyerror`, which is apparently defined. Please edit your question to include a [mre], consisting of the exact files you are using and all of the commands you ran in order, along with all error messages.

Comment: By the way, `yywrap() {}` is really awful. It's Undefined Behaviour because `yywrap` must return an `int` and that function doesn't return anything. (which doesn't even specify the return type, also incorrect). Brushing it under the rug ("it is giving me a warning which I'm going to ignore for now") is a pretty good sign that you should find a different tutorial. Try reading the introduction to the [Bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html) (skip the section on GLR parsers) and go through the  [examples](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Examples)